# How to count RNA sequencereads using custom made python scripts?

Tags: genomics, rna

I am trying to do RNA seq analysis and my goal is to filter gene counts less than 5 using custom made python scripts. The code chunk goes as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#Load relevant modules
import sys
    
#Read in the HTseq gene count output files for each of the 8 samples
inputlist = [sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3], sys.argv[4], sys.argv[5], sys.argv[6], sys.argv[7], sys.argv[8]]  
##Determine the genes with sufficient coverage
#Set up a variable to hold genes with sufficient coverage in any of the 8 samples
genelist = []

#For each HTseq file
for i in range(len(inputlist)):
    #Open it
    inputfile = open(inputlist[i], 'r')
    #For each line
    for line in inputfile:
        #Determine the number of reads/transcripts for this gene
        splitline = line.strip().split('\t')
        #Does it pass the threshold?
        if int(splitline[1]) >= 5: 
            #If so, add it to list
            if not splitline[0] in genelist:
                genelist.append(splitline[0])
                    
    #Close the file
    inputfile.close()
    
#Write out the list of sufficiently expressed genes
outputlist = open(sys.argv[9], 'w') 
    
for gene in genelist:
    outputlist.write(gene + '\n')
        
outputlist.close()
##Filter each of the HTseq files for only sufficiently expressed genes across our samples
#For each HTseq file
    
for i in range(len(inputlist)):
    #Open it
    inputfile = open(inputlist[i], 'r')
    
#Open an output 'filtered' file
outputfile = open(sys.argv[i+10], 'w')
    
#For each line
for line in inputfile:
    #Determine the gene
    splitline = line.strip().split('\t')
        
    #Is it in our list?
    if splitline[0] in genelist:
        #If so, write out the original line
        outputfile.write(line)
            
#Close the files
inputfile.close()
outputfile.close()
```

`python filtercounts.py 'wth1count.txt' 'wth2count.txt' 'wth3count.txt' 'wth4count.txt' '99h1count.txt' '99h2count.txt' '99h3count.txt' '99h4count.txt' 'genelist.txt' 'wth1filtered.txt' 'wth2filtered.txt' 'wth3filtered.txt' 'wth4filtered.txt'  '99h1filtered.txt' '99h2filtered.txt' '99h3filtered.txt' '99h4filtered.txt'`

The program works fine but at the end of the code execution I am not getting the last two output files '99h3filtered.txt' '99h4filtered.txt'.

Comment: If you want to provide a small sample data I will show you hwo to do it in pandas

Answer (score 1):

What software are you using for the next step?  DESeq in R will do this filtering for you in one line.

I think a more typical way to do this would be to make your entire gene count matrix, and then remove rows where the max value for that row is < 5.  Your way, you have to go through each file twice; once to know which genes to keep, and then again to actually remove lines.